# finding the local and global efficiency of a graph using networkx

Tags: networkx

I am trying to find the local and global efficiency of a graph using networkx. I have a weighted graph where the weights of the links are greater than 0. So, the adjacency matrix (adj) is weighted. I tried the following code

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx. Graph(adj)      # adj is the weighted adjacency matrix
eff=nx.global_efficiency(G)
```

However, I am getting the follwoing error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'global_efficiency'

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was due to the older version of networkx that I was using. I was able to successfully run the above code after upgrading the networkx version.

Thank you.